# How can I make a table with a date range labeling weekdays and weekends (joinable by date) in python?

Tags: python, date, datetime, weekday, datetimeindex

I've never worked with DataTimeIndex. It's giving me a headache as everything I normally would try is not working. I've tried converting to datetime and I'm still unable to just make a weekday column using date.weekday or .dayofweek. Can someone please assist?

```
date_list = pd.date_range(trainset['date'].min(), trainset['date'].max(), freq='d', name='date_val')


date_list['date_val'] = date_list['date_val'].dt.date
date_list['Weekdays'] = date_list.date_val.dt.dayofweek()
```

Answer (score 0):

I converted to dataframe and then reset the index because that was what was making it hard for me. If someone has a solution for how to do it with indexes, please do let me know. I'll read up on them in the mean time. thanks.

```
date_list = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(trainset['date'].min(), trainset['date'].max(), freq='d', name='date_val'))

date_list = date_list.reset_index()
date_list['Weekdays'] = date_list.date_val.dt.dayofweek()
```